# Using array elements as variable inside FOR loop in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I am trying to get some values from file and use each of them in another command.

Here is my script:

```
set "file=temp.txt"
set /A i=0

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file%") do (
    set /A i+=1
    call echo %%i%%
    call set array[%%i%%]=%%a
    call set n=%%i%%
)

del temp.txt
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do (
    call echo job= %%array[%%i]%%
    set variable=%%array[%%i]%%
    call echo !variable!
    java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://epbyminw1388:9091/ get-job !variable!
)
```

The output is:

```
job= backup
%array[1]%
job= P2
%array[2]%
job= Pipeline
%array[3]%
job= Pipeline-c
%array[4]%
```

The last string doesn't work correctly. It uses %array[1]%, %array[2]%, ...  instead of variable value.
 
I need to use string values of array elements inside my script. It should call commands like:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://epbyminw1388:9091/ get-job backup
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://epbyminw1388:9091/ get-job P2
etc. one by one
```

Comment: What is variable `value` set to? Try to put `call` before your `java` command line and replace `!variable!` by `%%variable%%` there...

Comment: Your batch code reduced to a working solution using delayed expansion: Line 1: `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` Line 2: `set "JobsFile=temp.txt"` Line 3: `set "JobsCount=0"` Line 4: `for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%JobsFile%") do set /A "JobsCount+=1" && set "JobsArray[!JobsCount!]=%%I"` Line 5: `del "%JobsFile%"` Line 6: `for /L %%I in (1,1,%JobsCount%) do java.exe -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://epbyminw1388:9091/ get-job !JobsArray[%%I]!` Line 7: `endlocal`

Comment: @Mofi Thank you so much